# TypeScript | unable to install type script

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm

[image]Unable to install typescript with below error :

npm WARN registry Using stale package data from https://registry.npmjs.org/ due to a request error during revalidation.

npm ERR! code E500

npm ERR! 500 Internal Server Error: typescript@https://registry.npmjs.org/typescript/-/typescript-3.0.1.tgz

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

npm ERR!     C:\Users\Sony\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2018-09-01T13_12_48_404Z-debug.log

Comment: Which version of npm/node are you using? Might be an issue cause of an older version.

Comment: node --version is v8.11.3

&

npm version is 5.6.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a global problem. They say that it will be fixed in weekend [here](https://status.npmjs.org/incidents/v22ffls5cd6h)

A temporary solution:

Open Terminal 
`dig registry.npmjs.com @1.1.1.1`

It will give you an IP address. Than
add it to your etc/hosts file.

[How to add IP address to etc/hosts OSX/Linux/Windows](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/27350/beginner-geek-how-to-edit-your-hosts-file/)

Restart maybe required. After that, you can use `npm`
It worked for me.

**UPDATE**

Problem is solved. You may remove the line from your etc/hosts file.